# How to deserialise a BLOB and then extract key/value pairs with Java

Tags: java, blob

An SQL Server database holds some data like this:

```
keyname(string) / value(int)
M01 / null
M02 / 10
M03 / 4
M99 / null
```

These data are in BLOBs in the db, I found out how to deserialise the BLOBs to a string and this is what's inside:

```
[self (wt.fc.ObjectReference), OR:wt.workflow.work.WfAssignedActivity:823568909, not required]
[primaryBusinessObject (wt.fc.WTObject), VR:wt.change2.WTChangeActivity2:823534981, not required]
[M01 (int), null, not required]
[M02 (int), null, not required]
[M03 (int), null, not required]
[M04 (int), null, not required]
[M05 (int), null, not required]
[M06 (int), null, not required]
[M07 (int), null, not required]
[M08 (int), null, not required]
[M09 (int), null, not required]
[M10 (int), null, not required]
[M11 (int), null, not required]
[M12 (int), null, not required]
[M13 (int), null, not required]
[M14 (int), null, not required]
[M15 (int), null, not required]
[M16 (int), null, not required]
[M99 (int), 1, not required]
```

I tried to write some Java to extract the key/value pairs, it works but it's very slow. Is there a better way to get the value for a given key out of this string. E.g. M99 is 1 in the example above.

```java
package ext.tools;

import wt.util.WTException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import wt.pom.DatastoreException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import wt.method.RemoteMethodServer;
import wt.pds.PDSEncoder;

public class BLOBConversionHelper {
    //pass in a BLOB (Object o) and Workflow Variable name (String s)
    //returns the value of the workflow variable (int)
    public static int getValueFromBLOB(final Object o, final String s) throws WTException {
        // deserizlize method similar to wt.pds.ConversionHelper
        Object object = null;
        if (RemoteMethodServer.ServerFlag) {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
            PDSEncoder encoder = null;
            try {
                encoder = PDSEncoder.getEncoder();
                if (o instanceof String) {
                    objectInputStream = encoder.setInput((String)o);
                }
                else {
                    InputStream binaryStream = null;
                    if (o instanceof Blob) {
                        binaryStream = ((Blob)o).getBinaryStream();
                    }
                    else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
                        binaryStream = (InputStream)o;
                    }
                    if (binaryStream != null) {
                        objectInputStream = encoder.setInput(binaryStream);
                    }
                }
                if (objectInputStream != null) {
                    object = objectInputStream.readObject();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new DatastoreException(ex);
            }
            finally {
                if (objectInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        objectInputStream.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex2) {}
                }
                PDSEncoder.freeEncoder(encoder);
            }
        }

        //find the comma after the variable name and the next comma after
        //the split the string
        //convert the string to an int
        int val;
        int indexOfs = object.toString().indexOf(s);
        int indexOfcomma = object.toString().indexOf(",", indexOfs);
        int indexOfEndcomma = object.toString().indexOf(",", (indexOfcomma + 1));
        String checkNull = object.toString().substring((indexOfcomma + 2),(indexOfcomma + 6));
            
        if (checkNull.equals("null")){
            val = 0;
        } else {        
            try {
                val = Integer.valueOf(object.toString().substring((indexOfcomma + 2),indexOfEndcomma));
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                val = 99999;
            }
        }
            
        return val;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If all the values are in a single BLOB, I would expand getValueFromBLOB to `public static Map<String, Integer> convertBLOB(final Object o)` which will parse the whole blob once.

Comment: Strange you'd use BLOB instead of JSON text to store that data

Comment: @Richard yes, they are in a single BLOB, I posted another question about how to make a map of the object

Comment: @OneCricketeer idk why they used BLOB, would be easier for if they were normal columns/rows in db table